# C: is it possible to expand marcos before pasting, but not recursively?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I know that C preprocessor will not expand macros when ## is present, so 2 levels of macros are needed:

```
#define CAT_(a,b) a##b
#define CAT(a,b)  CAT_(a,b)
```

But this always causes recursive macro expansion.

For example, if I want `R(U)` to expand into `R_U1`, while `U` is a macro unfortunately defined as another macro (for configuration), neither of the following code works for me:

**A**

```
#define U1    1
#define R_U1  2
#define U     U1
#define R(u)  R_##u
```

**B**

```
#define U1        1
#define R_U1      2
#define U         U1
#define C(a, b)   a##b
#define R(u)      C(R_, u)
```

For **A** `R(U)` expands to `R_U`, which means the macro `U` was not expanded. For **B** I got `R_1`, which apparently got expanded recursively.

So, is it possible to get `R_U1` with `R(U)`? (Not limited to the general way I am doing it.)

Comment: isn't this solvable by the old trick? `#define  RR(u) R_##u`  `#define R(u) RR(u)`

Comment: @M.M My parameter is a macro, but I only want to expand it once rather than recursively. The old trick does `R_1` rather than `R_U1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this is not possible (assuming that you mean to be asking if you can get `U` to *expand* to `U1`, and then be pasted).

Let's assume for a start we just have this:

```
#define U1 1
#define U  U1
U
```

...then the `U` on this line, being an invocation of an object-like macro, will expand to its replacement list (`U1`).  That will be rescanned with `U` painted blue.  The rescan finds `U1` as an object-like macro, and replaces it with its replacement list (`1`), which is then rescanned with `U1` painted blue.  The result is just `1`.  Let's call this entire sequence here is *a scan*.

So, if you apply a scan, you get `1`.  If you don't, you just have `U`.

> I know that C preprocessor will not expand macros when ## is present,

That's true, but doesn't help you.  Supposing we add these macros in:

```
#define CAT_(a,b) a##b
#define CAT(a,b)  CAT_(a,b)
#define X x_rl
#define Y y_rl
```

...then `CAT_(X,Y)` results in `XY`, whereas `CAT(X,Y)` results in `x_rly_rl`.  This is by application of *argument substitution* rules.  Argument substitution is the function-like macro equivalent of replacing an object-like macro invocation with its replacement list.  If a parameter appears in the replacement list, and is neither being stringified nor a participant of a paste operation, then the corresponding argument is scanned before replacing the parameter.  If the parameter is in the replacement list, and *is* being stringified or is a participant in a paste operation, the argument replaces the parameter without a scan.  But again, that just means that if the scan applies, you get `1`; if not, you get `U`.

Let's make this slightly more complex for illustration:

```
#define STRINGIFY(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define PAS(X,Y) STRINGIFY(X##Y)
#define STR(X) STRINGIFY(X)
PAS(U,) // expands to "U"
STR(U)  // expands to "1"
```

Here, `STRINGIFY` is used as a "stopper"; argument substitution happens first here, but since this is stringifying its arguments, they are not expanded.  Knowing this, `PAS` shows the effect of argument substitution without applying the scan; `STR` the effect when applying the scan.  `STR`'s expansion steps look like this:

```
STR(U)
STRINGIFY(1) // U evaluated before replacing X in STR's replacement list
#1
"1"
```

`PAS`'s looks like this:

```
PAS(U,)
STRINGIFY(U ## <empty-placeholder>) // U *not* evaluated before replacing X
STRINGIFY(U)
#U
"U"
```

There's no "tricky middle" solution here.  Using the paste operator to hold off on argument substitution scans gives you `U`.  Not using it gives you `1`.

The only other scan is rescan and replacement.  During this scan, macros are "painted blue" so that they can no longer expand.  But this doesn't help you either.  To wind up with `U1` in an intermediate step, you need `U1` painted blue.  But it only gets painted blue while expanding `U1`, and the only story there is for `U1` to get replaced with `1`, then for that to get rescanned, resulting in no further work, after which `U1` is unpainted.

Those three tricks: Don't evaluate `U`, evaluate `U` recursively, and evaluate `U` with some blue paint stopping a step somewhere, are pretty much the only tools at your disposal.  None of those can get your `U` to become `U1` in any intermediate step (long enough to apply a paste operator to).

Comment: That is indeed what I am wondering. Thanks for the explanation!